# Why isn't my Link working correctly in my about.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When I click the link it doesn't do anything at all and I'm not too sure as to why.

Here is my app.js file.

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from "../src/pages/homepage";
import About from "./pages/about"
import Navbar from "../src/components/navbar";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my about.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function about(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Link to="/" >
                click to go back
            </Link>
        </div>

    );
}
export default about;
```

I tried using a button, using  tags...etc but nothing seems to happen when I click anything.

Answer (score 0):

<Route path="/about" element={} />

The "a" is lower cased in the file, but in the route element you write it with a Pascal case.

Comment: the import is default so that's ok to use any other name. I think this happens because about is actually not a component(doesn't start with upper-case letter).

Comment: Ye could be that, I have just always been told to name components files with an uppercase and have never ran into a problem like this.